# Objective C HTML Request

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, nsstring, nsdata

I am just starting out in Xcode and wanted to try and make a simple app where you press a button and it creates a html post request and returns the html in a string i can't then fiddle with. I realise i would be better server using path or soap or xml, but this is step 1 for me.

The problem i am having is that I can't understand why i get null data returned after my request. I think it might be something to do with me trying to convert the NSData variable into a string?

below is the code for the button press, and below that is the NSLog Details of what is coming out.

Could anyone please suggest what i am doing wrong with this?

Cheers,
John

-(IBAction)buttonTouchedSignIn{

```
NSString *userName = @"mymadeupuser";
NSLog (@"NSString userName = %@\n\n", userName);
NSString *password = @"1234";
NSLog (@"NSString password = %@\n\n", password);

NSString *url = @"http%3A%2F%2Fmyotherwebsite.com%3A80%2Fsomthing%2Fweb%2Faction%2Flogin.do%3FtargetURL%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fsomwherelse.com%2Fsite3%2Fweb3%2Faction%2FmyAccountMenu.do%3Fdscnt%3D0%26vid%3DBSU";
NSLog (@"NSString url = %@\n\n", url);

// Create the username and password string.
// username and password are the username and password to login with
NSString *postString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"bor_id=%@&bor_verification=%@&url=%@",userName, password, url];
NSLog (@"NSString postString = %@\n\n", postString);    

// Create the URL request
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://mywebsite.com/somthing/"]];  
NSLog (@"NSString NSMutableURLRequest = %@\n\n", request);

NSData *requestData = [postString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
[request setHTTPBody: requestData];  // apply the post data to be sent   
NSLog (@"NSData requestData = %@\n\n", requestData);    

// Call the URL
NSURLResponse *response;  // holds the response from the server
NSLog (@"NSURLResponse response = %@\n\n", response);


NSError *error;   // holds any errors
NSLog (@"NSError error = %@\n\n", error);     

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse:&response error:&error];  // call the URL
NSLog (@"NSData returnedData = %@\n\n", returnData); 


//If the response from the server is a web page, dataReturned will hold the string of the HTML returned.
NSString *dataReturned = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"returned htmlASCII is:  %@\n\n", dataReturned);   

NSString *dataReturned2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"returned htmlUTF8 is:  %@\n\n", dataReturned2);
```

}

Here is the NSLog output for all the variables
2012-03-29 12:10:04.306 MyApp[2635:f803] NSString userName = mymadeupusername

Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
2012-03-29 12:10:16.520 MyApp[2635:f803] NSString password = 1234

2012-03-29 12:10:16.520 MyApp[2635:f803] NSString url = http%3A%2F%2Fsomewebpage.com%3A80%2Fweb2%2Fweb3%2Faction%2Fsigin.go%3FtargetURL%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fsomewebpage.com%2Fweb2%2Fweb3%2Faction%2Fyouraccounts.go%3Fdscnt%3D0%26vid%3DBSU

2012-03-29 12:10:16.521 MyApp[2635:f803] NSString postString = bor_id=joeliot&bor_verification=1234&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsomewebpage.com%3A80%2Fweb2%2Fweb3%2Faction%2Fsigin.go%3FtargetURL%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fsomewebpage.com%2Fweb2%2Fweb3%2Faction%2Fyouraccounts.go%3Fdscnt%3D0%26vid%3DBSU

2012-03-29 12:10:16.522 MyApp[2635:f803] NSString NSMutableURLRequest = https://somewebpage.com/pds?func=login&calling_system=blah&term1=short&company=BSU>

2012-03-29 12:10:16.522 MyApp[2635:f803] NSData requestData =

2012-03-29 12:10:16.650 MyApp[2635:f803] NSURLResponse response = (null)

2012-03-29 12:10:16.651 MyApp[2635:f803] NSError error = (null)

2012-03-29 12:10:17.422 MyApp[2635:f803] NSData returnedData = (null)

2012-03-29 12:10:17.422 MyApp[2635:f803] returned htmlASCII is:

2012-03-29 12:10:17.422 MyApp[2635:f803] returned htmlUTF8 is:

Comment: Do not use SOAP and do not use XML. Both are bad in small mobile systems. Especially SOAP.

Comment: thanks for the heads up Adam, I was planning on just doing some regex from the html and populating some table thingies with the strings. Probably not the way anyone with sense would proceed, but work with what you know and all that....

Comment: JSON is probably the best for data passing, just FYI. There is a google IO talk (can't find it) comparing the relative power requirements for receiving and parsing XML vs. JSON vs. something else, and JSON is way more efficient than XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things I see:

1) You need to set the method as POST. Use setHTTPMethod on your request.

2) You need a content lenght Do something like: [request setValue:length forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"]; where length is a string representation of the number of bytes you are posting.

3) You probably need to set the host to the hostname of the server. This depends a bit per server, but they tend to reject things not for their hostname(s). Use setValue again.

4) You should probably have a content-type. Again, depends on the server, but most certainly good practice to have.

5) UTF8 string encoding is nicer than ascii, most of the web plays better with it.

I hope at least one of those helps. Good luck.

Comment: thanks a bunch! did a quick google for how to set post method and content type and by the simple addition of 2 lines :) i am getting some html flowing into my label :) what next, heaven knows, but its a start!    

just added these two:
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"text/html" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];